# unique_ptr with virtual classes

Tags: c++

Its probably something really dumb, but I do not understand the g++ output I am getting. I am trying to hold a pointer to a derived object to a virtual base class. When I run the commented code, it works fine and as expected, holding it in the unique_ptr does not compile.

Error message:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/memory:81:0,
                 from 2:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unique_ptr.h: In instantiation of 'typename std::_MakeUniq<_Tp>::__single_object std::make_unique(_Args&& ...) [with _Tp = base; _Args = {derived*}; typename std::_MakeUniq<_Tp>::__single_object = std::unique_ptr<base>]':
20:66:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unique_ptr.h:765:69: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'base'
     { return unique_ptr<_Tp>(new _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)); }
                                                                     ^
4:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'base':
6:18: note:     virtual void base::foo()
7:18: note:     virtual void base::bar()
```

Sample code

```
#include <memory>

class base {
public:    
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};

class derived : public base {
public:
    derived() { }
    void foo() override { printf("foo\n"); }
    void bar() override { printf("bar\n"); }
    void foobar()  { printf("foobar\n"); }
};

int main()
{
  std::unique_ptr<base> dv = std::make_unique<base>(new derived());
  
  dv->foo();
  reinterpret_cast<derived*>(dv.get())->foobar();
  //base* dv = new derived();
  //dv->foo();
  //reinterpret_cast<derived*>(dv)->foobar();
}
```

I know it has to be some dumb error or a big missunderstanding from my part, but I found no solution when searching for virtual base classes with unique_ptr

Comment: `std::make_unique` takes arguments to forward to a constructor, not a pointer to a newly created object. `... = std::make_unique<derived>();`.

Comment: I'm kind of surprised that you have [`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) since it's a C++14 feature, and you're using GCC 4.9 which is ancient and doesn't even have full C++11 support.

Comment: Also, a word of unrelated but helpful advice: Please don't use `reinterpret_cast` for casting between related types. Actually, don't use `reinterpret_cast` *at all* if you can. The number of uses where it actually does what you would expect is vanishingly small, and it's very easy to shoot yourself in the foot by using it incorrectly.

Comment: Read the error messages carefully.  `std::make_unique<base>(new derived());` attempts to construct an instance of `base`, initialising it with the result of `new derived()` (which has type `derived *`).    An instance of `base` cannot be constructed, since it has pure virtual functions (which is what the error message reports).   Also, there is no constructor of `base` that can accept an argument of type `derived *`.

Comment: Instead of `reinterpret_cast` to downcast, you should use `dynamic_cast` to downcast.  However, using `dynamic_cast` to downcast is a violation of SOLID principle LSP, and is a Very Bad Code Smell™ that suggests a flawed design.  And `base` probably should also have a virtual destructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the argument(s) to `std::make_unique` should be those required by the constructor of the created object. In your case, this would be an empty argument list (the `derived` constructor needs no argument). Further, you cannot create a `unique_ptr` object to your virtual base class; instead, that should be a pointer to the derived class.

Here is a version that compiles (you don't need to explicitly cast the `unique_ptr` object: polymorphism will take care of that):

```cpp
#include <memory>

class base {
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual void bar() = 0;
    virtual ~base() = default; // Add virtual destructor, to be safe!
};

class derived : public base {
public:
    derived() { }
    void foo() override {
        printf("foo\n");
    }
    void bar() override {
        printf("bar\n");
    }
    void foobar() {
        printf("foobar\n");
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<base> dv = std::make_unique<derived>();
    dv->foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively (and this *may* be part of your confusion), you can use the `unique_ptr` constructor, instead of calling `make_unique` as the first line of your `main`:

```cpp
    std::unique_ptr<base> dv{new derived()};
```

Comment: Oh damned, right, I mixed those two up. Man, the error message was not helpful for me.

Answer (score 3):

Two problems here: Your base class does not have a virtual destructor. This is required for `unique_ptr` to be able to destroy the object correctly.

Second, the call to `make_unique` should look like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<base> dv = std::make_unique<derived>();
```

This will create a new `unique_ptr<derived>` (because you want to create a `derived` object), which converts implicitly to a `unique_ptr<base>`.
In your initial example, you were creating a `unique_ptr<base>` (which holds a `base` object, not a `derived` object pointed to by a `base` pointer!), which you then tried to initialise from a `derived*` (the result of the `new derived` expression). This is what caused the compiler error message you saw.